# Creating a loop in R for feature selection

Tags: r, loops, feature-selection

I would like to create a loop for feature selection in the train data set
Here is a code for a single run:

```
set.seed(1234)
splitIndex <- createDataPartition(data$disease, p = .75, list = FALSE, times = 1)
train <- data[ splitIndex,]
test  <- data[-splitIndex,]

#feature selection 
library(Boruta)

set.seed(1234)
boruta_output <- Boruta(disease ~ ., data=train, doTrace=2,maxRuns= 500, ntree=1000)  
names(boruta_output)
boruta_signif <- getSelectedAttributes(boruta_output, withTentative = TRUE)
print(boruta_signif) 
roughFixMod <- TentativeRoughFix(boruta_output)
boruta_signif <- getSelectedAttributes(roughFixMod)
print(boruta_signif)
imps <- attStats(roughFixMod)
imps2 = imps[imps$decision != 'Rejected', c('meanImp', 'decision')]
head(imps2[order(-imps2$meanImp), ])
```

I would like it to run for certain number of seeds and save the results in a data.frame

```
n=c(1234,777,123,5656,2213,9,100)
for (i in n) {
   set.seed(n)
```

Thank you for help!
George

I have tried the code above

Comment: Something like `out <- lapply(c(1234,777,123,5656,2213,9,100), function(seed) { set.seed(seed); rest_of_your_expression; })`, and then `out` will be a list, length 7, each element being a full process. On there, assuming that each element is a frame with the same names, you can do `do.call(rbind, out)` or `dplyr::bind_rows(out, .id="iter)` or `data.table::rbindlist(out, idcol="iter")` to get a frame, where the `iter` column contains which (of the seven) iteration a row is from.